# C: Dynamic format specifier

Tags: c, printf

I wish to write an arbitrary number of *parameters* to a buffer in C. The number of parameters may vary and so the format specifier of `sprintf()` must change accordingly.

I have found a solution (below), which works, but it isn't simple to read. Could the **format specifier** be defined as a **macro**, which changes based on the parameters used and could the solution be made more straightforward?

```
#define USE_PARAM_1          1
#define USE_PARAM_2          0
#define USE_PARAM_3          1
```

...

```
    char buf [128];

    sprintf(buf, "Params:"
#if (USE_PARAM_1 == 1)
        "\tparam_1: %d"
#endif
#if (USE_PARAM_2 == 1)
        "\tparam_2: %d"
#endif
#if (USE_PARAM_3 == 1)
        "\tparam_3: %d"
#endif
#if (USE_PARAM_1 == 1)
        ,param_1
    #endif
#if (USE_PARAM_2 == 1)
        ,param_2
#endif
#if (USE_PARAM_3 == 1)
        ,param_3
#endif
    );
```

`printf("%s\n", buf)` would show:

```
Params: param_1: 1  param_3: 3
```

**EDIT:**

Let's assume the parameters are actually smaller buffers themselves and knowing, which was included is not important, because each of the buffers already contains the information:

```
    char buf [1024];

    sprintf(buf, "Buffers:"
#if (USE_BUF_1 == 1)
        "\t%s"
#endif
#if (USE_BUF_2 == 1)
        "\t%s"
#endif
#if (USE_BUF_3 == 1)
        "\t%s"
#endif
#if (USE_BUF_1 == 1)
        ,buf_1
    #endif
#if (USE_BUF_2 == 1)
        ,buf_2
#endif
#if (USE_BUF_3 == 1)
        ,buf_3
#endif
    );
```

`printf("%s\n", buf)` would show:

```
Params: this_is_buf_1   this_is_buf_3
```

Comment: Do you actually need to do this at compile time or could you be better served by something that can be changed at runtime?

Comment: Preferably at compile time to save space (embedded application).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca how would you do it at runtime?

Comment: I would build the string one piece at a time with `strncat`, but that wouldn't probably be very elegant anyway.

Comment: Is there an actual question here somewhere? All I see is a cool hack I'd prefer to not reach production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially considering you haven't mentioned how many params you expect,
I'd simply do it dynamically:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int sprintf_vparams(char *Buf, int N /*number of int params*/, ...)
{
    //no bufsize checking
    va_list ap; va_start(ap,N);
    char *buf = Buf;
    buf += sprintf(buf,"Params: ");
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) buf += sprintf(buf,"\tparam_%d: %d", i+1, va_arg(ap,int));
    va_end(ap);
    return buf-Buf;
}
```

The function isn't the smallest (186B on x86-64 with buffer overflow checks disabled) but you won't have to generate static unique format strings at the call sites + the callsites will be just as big or tiny bit smaller than what you'd get if you used `sprintf` directly.

If you can reasonably expect your param count to be less then a certain number, you could use an inlinable switch:

```
static inline int sprintf_aparams(char *Buf, int N /*number of int params*/, int X[])
{
    #define P(Num) "\tparam_"  #Num ": %d"
    switch(N){
    case 0: return sprintf(Buf,"Params: ");
    case 1: return sprintf(Buf,"Params: " P(1), X[0]);
    case 2: return sprintf(Buf,"Params: " P(1) P(2), X[0], X[1]);
    case 3: return sprintf(Buf,"Params: " P(1) P(2) P(3), X[0], X[1], X[2]);
    case 4: return sprintf(Buf,"Params: " P(1) P(2) P(3) P(4), X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3]);
    case 5: return sprintf(Buf,"Params: " P(1) P(2) P(3) P(4) P(5), X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4]);
    case 6: return sprintf(Buf,"Params: " P(1) P(2) P(3) P(4) P(5) P(6), X[0], X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4], X[5]);
    default: abort(); /*not supported*/ return 0;
    }
    #undef P
}
#define MC_sprintf_params(Buf,...) sprintf_aparams(Buf, sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__ })/sizeof(int), (int[]){__VA_ARGS__})

//usage:
int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    MC_sprintf_params(buf,2,4,6,8,10,12); //print 6 params
}
```

This will be a true zero cost abstraction on a modern compiler such as gcc or clang.

Comment: I think the original question was a bit optimistic and this is as close as it gets. Thanks, I'm marking it correct.

Comment: @Alexander I've amended the answer.